# Overriding Yii components in the controller

Tags: php, yii, yii1.x

I have a Yii 1.x component loaded in the configuration file like so

```
$config['components']['simplesamlphp'] = array(
      'class' => 'application.components.yii-simplesamlphp.components.Simplesamlphp',
      'autoloadPath' => SAML_DIR.'/test2/lib/_autoload.php',
      'authSource' => 'default-sp',
);
```

I need to make the `autoloadPath` property dynamic based on who the user is in the controller. Is this possible? And if so how do I overwrite it?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way is to extend `Simplesamlphp` and configure property in `init()`:

```
class MySimplesamlphp extends Simplesamlphp {

    public $adminAutoloadPath;
    public $nonAdminAutoloadPath;

    public function init() {
        if (Yii::app()->user->isAdmin()) {
            $this->autoloadPath = $this->adminAutoloadPath;
        } else {
            $this->autoloadPath = $this->nonAdminAutoloadPath;
        }

        parent::init();
    }
}
```

And use new component in config:

```
$config['components']['simplesamlphp'] = array(
    'class' => 'MySimplesamlphp',
    'adminAutoloadPath' => SAML_DIR.'/test2-admin/lib/_autoload.php',
    'nonAdminAutoloadPath' => SAML_DIR.'/test2/lib/_autoload.php',
    'authSource' => 'default-sp',
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out overriding yii components is fairly easy even if you dont initialize it in the config.

```
$component  =   array(
                  'class' => 'application.components.yii-simplesamlphp.components.Simplesamlphp',
                  'autoloadPath' => SAML_DIR.'/'.$tenant_path.'/lib/_autoload.php',
                  'authSource' => 'default-sp',
                    ); //where $tenant_path is the directory of the component i need based on the tenant

    Yii::app()->setComponent('simplesamlphp',$component);
```

then use the component in your controller like so

```
    Yii::app()->simplesamlphp;
```

**Note** that you will only have access to the component within your controller method  so all i did was move the that code to its own class and call it when i needed to create a new instance of the component